# how to redirect to another app after login?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redirect

I have a React js application "**login**", which makes a request to the backend and gets the jwt. I need that after the authentication is done, the "login" application redirects to another react application (hosted on another server) which needs to use the jwt

Comment: Are you using the `react-router` in your React app?

Answer (score 1):

Framework-agnostic way

Whenever you get your `jwt` from the backend you call this to redirect:

```js
window.location.href = `https://path-to-another-app?token=${jwt}`;
```

Then, at the target app you can get your token like this:

```js
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
const jwt = url.searchParams.get("token");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect a user to another page via the [res.redirect](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#:%7E:text=res.redirect(%5Bstatus%2C%5D%20path)) method of ExpressJS.

So for example after a user logged in to your backend, you can do something like this:

```
app.all('/login', (req, res) => {
    let isAuthenticated = tryAuthenticate(req);
    
    if (isAuthenticated)
        return res.redirect('/anotherApplicationOnAnotherServer');
    
    else
        return res.redirect('/login');
});
```